# HTML video not playing in production

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, video

So I got a HTML video working on my local machine. It autoplays as soon as I visit the route, and I just created a DigitalOcean droplet to test my project in production, but the video is not auto-playing. It's a Laravel project with a Vue.js frontend. Here is the Vue.js code:

```js
mounted() {
  this.video = this.$refs.video;
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true
      })
      .then(stream => {
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.play();
      });
  }
},
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js" />
</head>

<body>
  <template>
      <video
        ref="video"
        id="video"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      /> 
  </template>
</body>

</html>
```

As soon as the page loads, the video should play automatically. Pressing the green button should draw an image onto the canvas at the space under the video.

Currently, there is just an empty space after pressing it, meaning that the canvas was created, but there is no image to show. In Chrome it shows black screen video.

Here is the website: http://164.90.233.74/vraceni
Here is expected behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/11oi2.jpg
Here is the full code (I don't know how JSFiddle works, but this code is running on local machine): https://jsfiddle.net/xa5L8q1j/1/

Comment: `<script>mounted() {` wont work, please show actual code

Comment: though prob a dupe of: [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia with http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299723/navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-with-http-server) localhost is treated as if its https

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: As @LawrenceCherone Said it is because localhost is hosted as https while your server is http, to fix that you can disabled chromes security or update your host as https.

Comment: tried running chrome from cmd - chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security and --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure it's still not working if thats what you meant.

Comment: paste this on your navigator chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure and then enable the option after that type your site it should work, dont forget to disable it.

Comment: Yes it does, I forgot to type in the site. Thanks.