# DOMException: Could not start video source in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on a webcam recorder app in JavaScript and WebRTC but when I click on the "Start Recording" button, I got this error:

```
Cannot access media devices:  DOMException: Could not start video source
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:43
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:42
```

And here's my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn-start-recording">Start Recording</button>
<hr>
<video id="my-preview" controls autoplay></video>
<script src="./scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
// when the user clicks on the button start video recording
document.getElementById("btn-start-recording").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
        // disable the start recording button
        this.disabled = true;

        // request access to the media devices
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: true,
            })
            .then(function (stream) {
                // display a live preview on the video element of the page
                setSrcObject(stream, video);

                // start to display the preview on the video element
                // and mute the video to disable the echo issue!
                video.play();
                video.muted = true;

                // initialize the recorder
                recorder = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
                    mimeType: "video/webm",
                    bitsPerSecond: 128000,
                });

                // start recording the video
                recorder
                    .startRecording()
                    .then(function () {
                        console.info("Recording video ...");
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Cannot start video recording: ", error);
                    });

                // release stream on stopRecording
                recorder.stream = stream;

                // enable the stop recording button
                document.getElementById("btn-stop-recording").disabled = false;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Cannot access media devices: ", error); // this is line 43
            });
    },
    false
);
```

---

I gave access to the browser microphone and camera on prompt and enabled it in Windows 10 settings.

I also tried in a live server from an extension in Visual Studio Code as well as I tried to run the file locally but this also did not work.

I am working on Windows 10 - Microsoft Edge Chromium 90 and Google Chrome 90.

When I tried in Firefox, I got `DOMException: Failed to allocate videosource`

Comment: Is your page being served with https?

Comment: @xdumaine I am not sure what do you mean by "served with https". But this is my Live server "http://127.0.0.1:5500/" - http when I try "https://127.0.0.1:5500/" - https Browser say The connection for this site is not secure - 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia with http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299723/navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-with-http-server)

Comment: @xdumaine I tried enabling unsecure content to my live server but also didn't and no luck. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getUserMedia` in the browser requires the page to be served over HTTPS (aka TLS, usually port 443, and browser has a valid little lock up in the address bar).

If you're using a web server serving the HTML page over http (plain text, port 80, page marked as insecure, and/or no lock in the address bar), the request to `getUserMedia` will fail.

Source: me https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-secure-origin-https/

### Edit

Another potential explanation is that another process is using the video camera at the same time. Have you verified that your webcam is not being used by another application? Consider completely killing all applications or browsers that have used your camera recently to try to free any process lock.

Comment: That usually happens, but `getUserMedia` doesn't fail from a local address. "Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and  http://*.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts

Comment: @NO_GUI I don't believe that's true in every browser.

Comment: True, there's a whole bunch of discrepancies between browsers:D But the poster said they tested on a couple different ones. Oooo the other process could definitely be a problem too

Comment: @NO_GUI Yes, I tested on Edge, Chrome, Firefox but no worked. :)

Comment: I checked that no other app is using my camera or microphone. anyway I will try to host project on real domain online with https and I will see it will work or not. Thanks for your effort :)